# Is it possible to bring down a network with DHCP discover?

Tags: dhcp, dhcp-server, denial-of-service

When a DHCP server receives a DHCP discover message it broadcasts the offer across the entire network. If a malicious machine joined a network and somehow began spamming DHCP discover messages, would the resulting high number of broadcasts from the DHCP server be able to bring the network down?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any broadcast traffic or switch flooding of a sufficiently high volume could bring a network down. A switching loop is a good example of this very thing. A malware infection is another good example. I've seen malware infections that used ARP to effectively bring a network to it's knees due to the volume of ARP broadcasts generated by the malware.

Comment: I once saw a malfunctioning device (a network integrated time register) spamming DHCP discover that caused the network to go down. Same principle.